# How to get author roles defined in quarto document to appear in output?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, quarto

The quatro documentation suggests that it is possible to assign roles to different authors (https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/front-matter.html#roles).

However, when rendered, the output document does not display these roles anywhere as far as I can tell. What can be done to have the roles show up in the output?

I am currently exporting to HTML, but will likley need to export to .docx as well eventually.

Example:

```
---
title: "Test"
author:
  - name: Josiah Carberry
    roles: conceptualization
format: html
---

## Document

content
```

[image: Output missing any mention of the author's role - specified as conceptualization in the YAML header]

Comment: Could you provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: are you using quarto version `1.4`? I assume this only works with the [prerelease](https://quarto.org/docs/download/prerelease).

Comment: @Julian I did not realize that would only be included in 1.4. Thanks for the tip, I am currently on 1.3.353!